# Mesh acting wierd compared to bones movement

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups

I'm working on a robot for a video game, and some of the bones act different than the rest. Some move different parts of the mesh with unequal force even though the weight is 1.0 on all affected parts. Another problem is were assigned vertices don't move at all even though they are part of the same mesh and weighted at 1.0.

Comment: they can be weighted 1 but doesn't mean that another bone has no influence on these vertices. To rig a robot you should use With Empty Groups, then assign the vertices to the groups they are supposed to be part of, this way you're sure no vertex will be part of a group it is not supposed to be part of

Comment: That's what I've done, no the vertices in question are only weighted to one bone/vertex group.

Comment: so maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=BYM5zbAe" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/BYM5zbAe/)

Here you go, I'm working on the one on the right, Armature.003 and it's child

Comment: so for example for the robot on the right, you need to give some correction to the elbow in Weight Paint mode, for the second robot from the right, the arm objects have not been parented to the arm bones, etc...

Comment: Only the right one matters, the others are throwaways. What corrections? No matter what I do I can't make the left elbow stop deforming, and the fingers are a nightmare

Answer (score 0):

For the shoulder, first select the armature, then shift select the mesh, and switch to *Weight Paint* mode. Display the right panel with <kbd>N</kbd> and choose *Blend > Mix*, disable *Front Faces Only* and enable *2D Falloff*.

[image]

Now select a bone and paint:

[image]

For the finger, as it needs a bit more precision, come back to *Edit* mode, select the vertices, in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Vertex Groups*, choose the vertex group they are supposed to be part of and click *Assign*. You can also use this list to remove some vertices from some groups. In the right menu, under + and -, you can sort the vertex groups by name.

[image]

Comment: Shoulder and that finger bone are not supposed to move, so I haven't spent any time on them. The problems i'm facing are with the right elbow and the mid/tip finger bones.

Comment: use the exact same process

Comment: I have, over and over again. With deform it deforms the mesh, which is bad since it's a robot. But without deform it doesn't move at all. Try rotating the FingerMidL1 bone, nothing except the tip moves with it. How do I share images?

Comment: Yes I've just tested, so you need to enable Deform and use the process I explain in the second part, select the vertices that are supposed to move, find the vertex group called FingerMidL1 and click Assign

Comment: I fixed it by creating new empty groups and starting over. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Ok I hope you've understood the principles, a bit confusing at the beginning for sure  ;)